# Collections of goods in OpenCart?

Tags: collections, opencart

First of all, sorry for my bad english.
Anybody know such extension for OpenCart 2.0.3.1 or how to do it with default functional collections of goods, for example: i have trousers, T-shirt all of these is collection spring-summer etc.

Comment: do you mean how to relate some products to a specific category?

Comment: No, i need to have categories and collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not common among e-commerse. But if i understand you right you want collections like: (Spring-summer) and then place the products that respresent the collection?

One thing you can do is to make some "top" categories which is the collections, and then place the other categories as sub-categories for it.

Example:

Spring-Summer
            - T-shirt
            - Trousers
Fall-Winter
            - T-shirt
            - Trousers

Where u will have the collections as top categories. hard to give you a exact answer if you don't precise more for your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood your idea and i will try to do this.